# "задолженность в 2 месяца" или "задолженность за 2 месяца"

Tags: стилистика

у вас задолженность аренды в 2 месяца.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно задолженность измеряется в денежных единицах, но возможны и другие варианты:

двухмесячная задолженность по аренде; задолженность арендатора (не аренды) за два месяца; задолженность за два месяца аренды.

Answer (score 1):

У вас задолженность аренды **за** 2 месяца.

Если б здесь была сумма задолженности, возможен был бы предлог **в**, но у нас имеется в виду срок аренды - задолженность по  оплате аренды **за сколько месяцев?**

Comment: Я бы даже сказал "задолженность **по аренде**".

Comment: Согласна, можно и так.